# Why this JS countdown doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, countdown

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function countdown(seconds, element)
{
    var count = seconds;
    var counter= setInterval(timer, 1000);

    function timer()
    {
        count--;
        if (count <= 0)
        {
            clearInterval(counter);
            return;
        }   
        element.innerHTML = "Seconds remaining: " + count;
    }
}
</script>


<h1 onload="countdown(100, this)"></h1>
```

So why innerHTML of the calling tag doensn't change?
I saw other codes, but i didn't see any error here.
I'm newbie on JS coding.

Comment: The interval is never set, `h1` element doesn't trigger `onload` event.

Comment: Yeah, just saw supported tags. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onload` function can be used on `<body`> tag, it doesn't seem to work on other tags. try adding it on `<body>`

```js
function countdown(seconds, element)
{
  var count = seconds;
  var counter= setInterval(timer, 1000);
  function timer()
   {
     count--;
     if (count <= 0)
     {
      clearInterval(counter);
      return;
     } 
     element.innerHTML = "Seconds remaining: " + count;
     //console.log(count);
   }
}

h1List=document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
  for(i=0;i<h1List.length;i++){
     countdown(100-i*3, h1List[i]);
  }
//countdown(100, document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0]);
```

```html
<h1></h1>
<h1></h1>
<h1></h1>
<h1></h1>
<!--<body onload="countdown(100,document.getElementsByTagName(`h1`)[0])">-->
```

Comment: I just put the missing } but my code doesn't work the same.

Comment: check my snippet and click on h1.it will work.Point is onload event does not work for h1

Comment: Ok, that was the problem.
I didn't know this. Thank you!

Comment: The problem is the following: I have many <h1> tags in my code, and each one needs to fire countdown() with different value in seconds once the page is loaded! So i need to find a different way to do it

Comment: It's more complicated than this because i need to get seconds value from php in a foreach loop.. But thank you for the help mate!

Comment: I just found a way to do what i wanted to do, and your code helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function countdown(seconds)
{
var count = seconds;
var counter= setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer()
{
count--;
if (count <= 0)
{
clearInterval(counter);
return;
}   
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Seconds remaining: " + count;
}}
</script>

<body onload="countdown(100)">
<h1 id="timer"></h1>
</body>
```

check this one out if you want to run timer on page load event

Comment: Actually I need to fire some sort of onload event because I have many tags with different seconds value that must countdown when the page is loaded.

Comment: so u want to fire countdown event from various tag on pageload right?